# Constructor injection issue

Tags: castle-windsor

When MainClass is created public MyWindsorClass(IMyInterface obj) {} is called and when MainClass2 is created public MyWindsorClass(IMyInterface obj) {} is also called when I'm expecting public MyWindsorClass() {} to be called.  What exactly am I doing wrong?I'm having an issue with constructor injection.  Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
        var objs = container.ResolveAll<IMyWindsorInterface>();
    }
}

public interface IMyWindsorInterface { }

public class MyWindsorClass : IMyWindsorInterface
{
    public MyWindsorClass() {}
    public MyWindsorClass(IMyInterface obj) {}
}

public interface IMyInterface { }
public class MyInjectedClass : IMyInterface{ }

<castle>
     <components>
        <component id="MainClass"
             service="CastleTest.IMyWindsorInterface, CastleTest"
             type="CastleTest.MyWindsorClass, CastleTest"
             inspectionBehavior="None"
             lifestyle="Transient">
       <parameters>
          <obj>${blah}</obj>
       </parameters>
        </component>
    <component id="MainClass2"
               service="CastleTest.IMyWindsorInterface, CastleTest"
               type="CastleTest.MyWindsorClass, CastleTest"
               inspectionBehavior="None"
               lifestyle="Transient" />
         <component id="blah" 
             service="CastleTest.IMyInterface, CastleTest" 
             type="CastleTest.MyInjectedClass, CastleTest" 
             inspectionBehavior="None"/>
     </components>
</castle>
```

When MainClass is created public MyWindsorClass(IMyInterface obj) {} is called and when MainClass2 is created public MyWindsorClass(IMyInterface obj) {} is also called when I'm expecting public MyWindsorClass() {} to be called.  What exactly am I doing wrong?  Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: I felt like all the answers to my questions in all these questions were never answered.  So should I accept a answer when it never answered my question?

Comment: no problem.  Anyway, anyone that can answer my question I'll be more than happy to accept you.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor will by default autowire all available dependencies. In your case, `IMyInterface` is available as a component so Windsor will choose the constructor that can satisfy the most dependencies.

You may change this behavior ad-hoc by removing the constructor from the component model so Windsor doesn't 'see' it any more:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += model => {
    if (model.Name == "MainClass2")
        model.Constructors.Remove(model.Constructors.First(c => c.Dependencies.Any(m => m.TargetType == typeof(IMyInterface))));
};
container.Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```

Comment: ... or by removing `MyInjectedClass` from the XML configuration altogether, since it looks like you don't really want it to be injected :)

Comment: @Igor: it *is* injected into the MainClass component.

Comment: This is an example.  I have about 10 objects I want to inject that implement IMyWindsorInterface.  Some of them require IMyInterface to be passed in and some don't.

Comment: @Michael: so? just filter all that require filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround above.  However the best approach might be to have a default class that implements IMyWindsorInterface and pass that into everything that doesn't require it?  I just wish there was a way you can shut off autowire.

Comment: @Michael: autowiring is *good* for you. It's a major improvement over manual wiring (which previous containers sported).

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer I don't think I can do that either because the application is designed to add new functionality without compiling the base code.  So if I add a new class that implements IMyWindsorInterface but doesn't require IMyInterface, I would have to change the code to tell it not to see the new class.

Comment: @Michael: and one step above this is registration by convention, which you simply can't have without autowiring...

Comment: autowiring might be a good thing but it would also be nice to tell it not to autowire.

Comment: @Michael: you seem to have bigger design issues... I just answered this concrete question with a concrete answer, but I recommend posting another question with your real design issues (this question seems to be just a symptom).

Comment: @Michael: generally speaking you should avoid having multiple constructors in your components as much as possible.